# Work out Standard Deviation from Probability and limits

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

I have been working out probability. Now I want to work out the standard deviation given the probability:

Mean = 1.3
Probability that a item is between 1.4-1.6 = 0.23

Work out the standard deviation. How to do this?

Comment: Are you working with a normal (also called Gaussian) probability distribution?

Comment: I believe so - yes.